# Highcharts click on a line graph to add point

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, highcharts

I have a use case in which I need to click on a line graph (highcharts). If there is no point already present on the line graph then I want to add a new point to the same line graph. 
For this purpose I searched through the highcharts api and found two events which might help me. These are *chart.events.click* and *plotoptions.series.click*. chart.events.click is only fired when I click on the empty plot area. And plotoptions.series.click is fired when I click anywhere on the line graph.

The problem is that in chart.events.click an *event* object is passed which provides *event.xAxis[0].value* and *event.yAxis.value*. These values are the actual coordinates that I want. In *plotoptions.series.click* the object that is passed offers various values like chartX chartY etc.; but these are not actual coordinates of my line graph. In simple words I need the functionality of chart.events.click in plotoptions.series.click, but have been unsuccessful so far. The work that I have done till now is here(found from stackoverflow and edited a bit) => http://jsfiddle.net/sp3tsnaz/T5ZJ6/

```
    var flag = false;
function getIndex(x, data){
                    var index = 0,
                        dLen = data.length;
                    for(var i = 0; i < dLen; i++){
                        if(data[i] > x){
                            index = i;
                            i = dLen;
                        }
                    }
                    if(x == data[index]){
                        return -1;   
                    } else {
                        return index;   
                    }

                }

var func = function (e) {
                //alert(1);
                if (flag == false) {
                // find the clicked values and the series
                var x = e.xAxis[0].value,
                    y = e.yAxis[0].value,
                    series = this.series[0],
                    xIndex = getIndex(x, series.xData), //get 'index' 
                    data = series.options.data; //get original data


                if(xIndex > 0){ //add new point only when X-value is different 
                    data.splice(xIndex, 0, [x, y]);
                    series.setData(data);
                }



                flag = false;
            }
        };

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart : {
            events: {
            click: func 
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                events: {
                    /*click: function(event) {
                        flag = true;
                        func(event);
                        console.log(this.name +' clicked\n'+
                              'cx:' + event.chartX + '\n' +
                             'cy:' + event.chartY + '\n'+
                             'px:' + event.pageX + '\n' +
                             'py:' + event.pageY + '\n'+
                              'sx:' + event.point.x + "\t" + 'sy:' +event.point.y);
                    }*/
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [[0,29.9] ,[1,71.5], [2,106.4], [3,129.2], [4,144.0], [5,176.0], [6,135.6], [7,148.5], [8,216.4], [9,194.1], [10,95.6], [11,54.4]]                
        }]
    });
});
```

I need an implementation in which I am able to click the line graph and add a point which "lies" on the existing curve.

Thankyou,

Comment: You want it to work in both scenerios?  A click on the background or the series?

Comment: Have you seen [this demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-click-to-add)? ;)

Comment: @PawełFus, that's interesting.  His problem is that with a `line` graph, clicking on the line fires the series click event and not the charts.  In the example you link to the series type is `scatter` and it looks like the chart click event fires regardless of where you click (expect on a point).  So maybe the solution is to just use a `scatter` chart.

Comment: Indeed - scatter chart doesn't have mouse tracker for line, only for points. Anyway, instead of built-in events, how about using click event on container? Then translate x/y mouse position to values on a chart. Like [in this plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/17/Annotations).